# Sharing pandas dataframe between classes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a project which creates a number of pandas dataframes. These get manipulated all sorts of ways depending on user input and then get displayed using a Class function. At times it may be necessary for parts of the dataframe to be changed from the Class. So in essence I need to pass the dataframe to the Class.

Right now I'm accomplishing this as such (where TableDisp is the class):

```
ui = TableDisp()
self.ui.my_df = self.my_df
```

I realize as an alternative that I could pass through the class initialization with something like...

```
ui = TableDisp(self.my_df)
```

... if I set up the class this way, but different instances of the Class need different df's (which would need to be clearly identified). I.e. I'd need to do something like...

```
class TableDisp(Frame):
    def __init__(self, my_df=None, another_df=None, more_df=None, still_more_df=None):
```

But with a dozen or so of these.

My current method is throwing ...

> SettingWithCopyWarning:

... whenever I make a change to a df from the Class, which I can ignore, but it is making me wonder if I'm doing this in the most pythonic way. Any thoughts?

Comment: Everytime you assign a dataframe to another variable, try using `pandas.DataFrame.copy(deep=True)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple fix I'd go with @Chris's comment using `DataFrame.copy()`. However, it seems to me that since the class only needs to hold one dataframe at a time, you could simplify your class definition like so:

```
class TableDisp(Frame):
    def __init__(self, df=None, df_type=None):
        if df_type == "type1":
            # Format df in a specific way
        elif df_type == "type2":
            # You get the idea
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unrecognised df_type")
```

Comment: This is a great idea